# Proofs of Arrow's Theorem

Tags: game-theory, algorithmic-game-theory, social-choice-theory

I read Philip J. Reny's paper ([Arrow’s Theorem and the Gibbard-Satterthwaite Theorem: A Unified Approach](http://home.uchicago.edu/~preny/papers/arrow-gibbard-satterthwaite.pdf))

What I cannot understand is step 5 of the proof of arrow's theorem.

I think figure 4 is a special case because the position of a,b,c are fixed in 1,...,N except n. So if everybody randomly chooses a sequence of preference without any fixed alternatives. The social ranking will still the same with Ln ?

In figure 4, If Ln's ranking is a,b,c....., will the social ranking be a,b,c...? Why?

Another proof in Noam Nisan's book ([Algorithmic game theory](http://www.cambridge.org/journals/nisan/downloads/Nisan_Non-printable.pdf))
, P234.

I cannot understand the proof of pairwise neutrality. I think it is almost the same with IIA. Is there anything different between them?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Figure 4 is a special case, which is used to prove the result in full generality in step 5. I believe the answer to your first question is Yes, $n$ is the dictator, so her preference relation coincides with the social welfare function. This is precisely what step 5 proves. For the same reason the answer to your second question is again Yes, but only using the full force of the theorem; I don't think that we could have made that conclusion ("if $L_n$'s ranking is $a \succ b \succ c \succ \cdots$ then the social ranking is $a \succ b \succ c$") at that stage of the proof. Note that $c$ is just an auxiliary alternative, and what we are really interested is the position of $a$ relative to $b$.

The definition of unanimity on Nisam is not the usual one. Normally unanimity (or Pareto efficiency) is defined as: if every agent ranks $a$ above $b$, then so must the social welfare function. Nisam's apparently weaker definition (he requires that the full preferences coincide, not just $a \succ_i b$ for all $i$) is equivalent to this because of IIA (do you see this?).

In any case, yes, pairwise neutrality is almost the same as IIA, the difference being that in IIA we compare $a$ with $b$ in both $\succ$ and $\succ'$, while pairwise neutrality considers a possibly different pair $(c,d)$ for $\succ'$. The claim basically proves that unanimity (as defined by Nisam) plus IIA imply pairwise neutrality. Note that IIA is indeed used, even though only unanimity is mentioned.

Comment: But I think in figure 5 b and a are still fixed in all preferences except n. So only c is arbitrarily chosen. So I think it is not a general case.

Comment: And about the differences of unanimity , are there any affections? I think unanimity on this book is equivalent to unanimity you said and transitivity. Is this right?

Comment: About pairwise neutrality, I cannot understand how to merge two preferences. And c≻a, b≻d are arbitrarily chosen?

Comment: I suppose you mean step 5, not figure 5 (which doesn't exist). In any case no, step 5 has full generality: $a$ and $b$ are fixed only in $n$'s preferences.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by transitivity here. (Note the difference between properties of the social preference relation $F(\succ_1,\ldots,\succ_N)$ and the function $F$. The former can be transitive, and always is; I don't know what transitivity means for the latter.)

Comment: What exactly isn't clear about the merging process? Note that we are _not_ asking that $a \succ_i b$ for all $i$, only that this occurs iff $c \succ_i' d$.

Comment: Could you explain how step 5 works? I am confused with this part...

Comment: About pairwise neutrality, I mean why he puts c just above a and d just below b here.

Comment: Step 5, you'll have to read and reread carefully until you understand it, no way around it. You start with an arbitrary profile and preferences and manipulate it repeatedly (using IIA) until you can use step 4. I certainly can't explain it better than Reny!

Comment: The merging is done in a way that preserves the order between $a$ and $b$, and between $c$ and $d$ (check!), and in a way that $c\succ_i a$ and $b \succ_i d$ for all $i$, so that we can use unanimity.

Comment: Thank you, now I can understand ^^